# Install4j: SQL Script and statement delimiter

Tags: sql, install4j

I try to run several SQL-Statements in an SQL Script action for an Oracle dbms inside an installer and as part of a JDBC container action.
The script is encoded as UTF-8, and contains several statements, delimited by ";" and a new line between each statement, like this

```
statement 1;
statement 2;
...
```

The statements contain installer variables that are replaced before execution. I used the semicolon as a statement separator in the SQL script action.
The first statement throws an error 
Error executing script line "CREATE user testconuser identified by xxx TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;",

> error message: "ORA-00911: invalid character"

The statement itselfs works fine within SQLPLUS, but the problems seems to be the semicolon, that is still part of the statement executed by install4j.
In a JDBC sql statement, semicolons are not valid.
I also tried to remove the semicolons from the statements and used "\n" as statement delimiter, but then the sql script actions fires all sql statements within the script at once, so it looks like the "\n" is not recognized.
I am using install4j 6.1.5 build 6349. The platform is windows and the sql script is build on windows.
Any idea what I should change?
Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used the semicolon as a statement separator in the SQL script action. The first statement throws an error Error executing script line

and

> I also tried to remove the semicolons from the statements and used "\n" as statement delimiter

Both are bugs in 6.1.5 and will be fixed in 6.1.6. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where you can verify that this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, will do and report if the problem is fixed then.
When will 6.16 be available as an "official build"?